# Running Jasmine tests from Node against code that uses RequireJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, jasmine, jasmine-node

Is it possible to run Jasmine from Node to test code that uses RequireJS?

I am using the [Jasmine NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine). I can run some tests from Node but can't work out how to test my code that uses RequireJS.

[V2 of jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/tree/Jasmine2.0#whats-new) (that supports Jasmine 2.x) has had RequireJS support removed.

Is there an incompatibility with the `require` keyword because this is used by Node and RequireJS? Perhaps I am misunderstanding something fundamental?
If I have to use a task runner I would favour

If anyone has any experience or thoughts to share, that would be greatly appreciated!

I am using:

- Node 0.10.24
- RequireJS 2.1.22
- Jasmine 2.3.4

Comment: I'd recommend trying out [Intern](https://theintern.github.io/). It's actually _easier_ to test code written using RequreJS modules with that testing library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jperezov. This looks interesting, and I need to look into it further, but the project currently has a whole suite of tests using Jasmine. If possible, we'd prefer a solution using this.

Comment: I mean, I'd imagine if support for RequreJS was removed from Jasmine, you'd have to write a script to transform your AMD code into whatever module types Jasmine requires. jQuery does something pretty nifty with [their build file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/build/tasks/build.js), where they run the RequreJS optimizer and strip out the `define` wrappers.